# Tags on a question don't match its revision history

Tags: bug, tags, revision-history

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77235806/why-is-the-address-of-a-constexpr-local-variable-not-a-constant-expression) today that seemed to be purely about C++, but was tagged Kotlin:

[image: question about pointers to constexpr local variables]

This was weird, so I decided to check the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77235806/revisions) to see when and why that tag was added. But... the revision history says the tag was **never** added. According to the revision history, no version of this question has ever been tagged Kotlin, even though the tag shows up on the question itself.

Any idea what could cause this? Is this somehow normal, or is it a bug?

([Wayback Machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20231102085529/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77235806/why-is-the-address-of-a-constexpr-local-variable-not-a-constant-expression) to the question's current state, in case the evidence the Kotlin tag was there disappears after someone edits the tags again.)